# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression in django

Tags: python, django, syntax, django-views, syntax-error

```
new_todo = Todo(text=request.POST['text'],instance.User=request.user)

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

What exactly went wrong here?

I just want the user who created the todo his name should be automatically relfected to the database.....So, I have done this in my create view...

Comment: `instance.User` is *not* valid? It is probably `Todo(text=request.POST['text'], user=request.user)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is `instance.User=...`. The left part (that's what *keyword* mean in this context) should be one of the variable names that `ToDo` constructor accepts.

Also, it's not django-specific, it's general python.

Comment: I have give like this User=request.user, but its not automatically reflecting the name of the user...Its just coming null

Comment: @NiladryKar: you have no control on what an argument does in a constructor (unless you wrote the class `ToDo` yourself). The only thing you can do is pass it the correct value for `request.user`. but that has nothing to do with the error you are getting.